# Same Context Path For Different Applications For SSO Login?

Tags: web-applications, single-sign-on, tomcat8, contextpath

Currently we have two Web applications running on different or same Tomcat server with different context path but same domain, we have provided a link to client  for the SSO login to other application using Auth0 .

Whenever client clicks on the provided link, browser requests through new context path and request redirected to the required application.

Now our requirement is to have the same context path for these two application so that it appears as a single application to client.

Is it possible? I haven't found any solution yet.